PDF shrinking when page height increases than A4 in java
I'm using java to print a pdf containing a single page receipt the height of which can vary depending on the number of items, now when this PDF becomes too long, the print shrinks to fit into the size of an A4 page instead of continuously printing.
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(path + "/PineAppleInvoice.pdf"));

                // Get the print service corresponding to the specified printer name

                javax.print.PrintService[] printServices = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();

                javax.print.PrintService targetPrintService = null;
                for (
                        javax.print.PrintService service : printServices) {
                    if (service.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("OneNote")) {
                        targetPrintService = service;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (targetPrintService != null) {
                    PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
                    printerJob.setPrintService(targetPrintService);
                    PDFPageable pageable = new PDFPageable(document);
                    printerJob.setPageable(pageable);
                    if (printerJob.printDialog()) {
                        printerJob.print();
                    }
                } else {
                    System.err.println("Printer not found: " + "OneNote");
                }

                document.close();

I'm creating the receipt with jasper reports but the jasperReport's print function gives the same issues. I've tried using most java APIs, it works fine when I use a 3rd party exe to print the same pdf but that's out of the question. Is there any way I can handle this in the code itself?
